# Twitter bootstrap 2 menu popup behave unexpectedly ,how can i fix this?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hava some code like this,but when i click the third btn-group(with the content "manage"),the submenu doesn't popup.Anyone knows why,thank you.

```
 <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">View</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Start/End<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">End</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Manage<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">paper</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">pen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code should works fine, make sure the path to your bootstrap files is correct.

You also need to remove redundant `>` after last `</li>` in your code:

```
<li><a href="#">pen</a></li>>
// -----------------------  ^ here ----------------
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/114659)**

Comment: thank you,that's my typo,i find the problem,I have a modal below those code(the modal body is form),but i still don't find a way to solve it.Any advice?

Comment: Can you create a bootply demo to show your problem?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yavivaji/1,sorry i don't find bootfly where can use bootstrap 2.3.1(which i am using).PS:I have tried bootstrap3 ,works fine.

Comment: I fix this by set the modal style "display:none",think you for your help.